# Umbraco - how to insert clickable images into page?

Tags: image, umbraco, umbraco7

I am a beginner with Umbraco. I am able to upload images to the Media Library and then put them onto the page, but for my sidebars I want the images to be clickable links to other parts of my site and other sites.

At the moment I am using the Rich Text Editor to write an anchor tag etc. but this seems ridiculous and I don't want content authors [attempting to be] writing HTML.

It seems like there should be a built-in data type for this, or a property on the image but I see nothing. Do I need to write my own Razor code as a DataType? This seems like such a common thing that I'm surprised there is not a built-in solution.

I'm using 7.2.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're already using the RTE, you can just select the image and click the Link button, then whatever you have selected (in this case the image) should become a link. No need to make your own HTML :-)

Comment: Thanks. Is this standard practice in the world of Umbraco?

Comment: Inside the RTE it is, but if you are doing "boxes" in a side bar, you might consider using the Grid datatype for your entire layout. Or check out Nested Content ( https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nested-content/ ), where you then build a document type consisting of an image and a link (either a content picker or a text field, I guess) and add them to the page.